# How to reshape the numpy array or list

Tags: python, list, numpy, matrix, reshape

I'm having trouble reshaping the matrix in python.

Suppose I have four (5,5,3) matrix

```
a = [[[0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0]],
     [[0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0]],
     [[0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0]],
     [[0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0]],
     [[0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0]]]

b = [[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]],
     [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]],
     [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]],
     [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]],
     [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]]

c = [[[2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2]],
     [[2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2]],
     [[2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2]],
     [[2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2]],
     [[2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2]],]

d = [[[3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3]],
     [[3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3]],
     [[3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3]],
     [[3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3]],
     [[3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3]],]
```

I want to put this matrix together in the form of (5,5,4,3). like

```
result = [[[[0,0,0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]], [[0,0,0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]], [[0,0,0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]], [[0,0,0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]], [[0,0,0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]],
          [[[0,0,0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]], [[0,0,0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]], [[0,0,0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]], [[0,0,0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]], [[0,0,0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]],
          [[[0,0,0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]], [[0,0,0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]], [[0,0,0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]], [[0,0,0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]], [[0,0,0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]],
          [[[0,0,0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]], [[0,0,0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]], [[0,0,0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]], [[0,0,0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]], [[0,0,0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]],
          [[[0,0,0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]], [[0,0,0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]], [[0,0,0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]], [[0,0,0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]], [[0,0,0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]]]
```

I would appreciate it if you could let me know if you have any good ideas for the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [`stack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html) them as numpy arrays and then convert back to list:

```
stacked = np.stack([a,b,c,d], axis=2).tolist()
```

Verify with your `result`: `np.array_equal(stacked, result)` return `True`.